# How to remove parts of a GET call in Groovy so I can use json slurper

Tags: json, groovy

Hi I need to remove parts of a response I'm getting from a REST call.

**the call that's getting returned is:**

URI: https://apiext.thisurl.com/ado/v1/listener
HTTP Version: 1.1
Headers:
{
Authorization: Basic ********
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
}
Content:
{
"subscriptionId": "5898cfds-aafds2223335-423004422e"
"notificationId": 13869
"id": "846714a-b461e-449e-9600-f68a9975d2f4"
"eventType": "workitem.updated"
"publisherId": "tfs"
"message": {
"text": "User Story #2202091 (0819 ado 2) update)"
"html": "<a href="https://dev.azure.com/zsETO/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=931ea459-abea-43db-9aed-eb489dee1e5e&id=22221">User Story #2202091 (0819 ado 2) updated by Darren"
"markdown": "[User Story #2202091](https://dev.azure.com/ZionsETO/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=931ea459-abea-43db-9aed-eb489dee1e5e&id=2202091) (0819 ado 2) updated by Darre"
}

**I need to remove the following parts of the call so I can use json slurper**

URI: https://apiext.thisurl.com/ado/v1/listener
HTTP Version: 1.1
Headers:
{
Authorization: Basic ********
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
}
Content:

**So the final result returns:**

{
"subscriptionId": "5898cfds-aafds2223335-423004422e"
"notificationId": 13869
"id": "846714a-b461e-449e-9600-f68a9975d2f4"
"eventType": "workitem.updated"
"publisherId": "tfs"
"message": {
"text": "User Story #2202091 (0819 ado 2) update)"
"html": "<a href="https://dev.azure.com/zsETO/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=931ea459-abea-43db-9aed-eb489dee1e5e&id=22221">User Story #2202091 (0819 ado 2) updated by Darren"
"markdown": "[User Story #2202091](https://dev.azure.com/ZionsETO/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=931ea459-abea-43db-9aed-eb489dee1e5e&id=2202091) (0819 ado 2) updated by Darre"
}

I've tried using drop as in

def removeParts = requestInfo.drop(70)

but some of the uri's in the response data vary in character length.  Was hoping to remove the content based on a key such as "URI:"

Any help would be appreciated

The call I'm sending to get this data is:

```
public def getNotificatonsDetails(collection, subId, notificationId) {
```

projectManagmentService.getProject(collection, project)

```
    def result = genericRestClient.get(
        contentType: ContentType.JSON,
        //requestContentType: ContentType.JSON,
        uri: "${genericRestClient.getTfsUrl()}/${collection}/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/${subId}/notifications/${notificationId}?",
        headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/json'],
        query: ['api-version':'7.0']
        )

    return result;

}
```

I'm calling this method in another class as:

```
def notificationDetails = subscriptionService.getNotificatonsDetails(collection, subId, notificationId)
```

I then drill down into notificationDetails to to get the requestInfo

```
def requestInfo = "${notificationDetails.details.request}"
```

The result is what's mentioned above with the URI,HTTP, and Headers data that I need to remove

Comment: how are you getting the response?

Comment: hi there, I added that to the original question

Comment: if you use a proper http-client, like `http-builder` it does the resource parsing for you and returns the JSON part of the response

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but do you know of any way to remove certain elements or sections from what's returned in the response?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to remove.

Comment: I would like to remove the URI:, HTTP Version:,, Authorization type:, Headers:, and Content: from the first part of the data returned in the GET call.  If you look at the first 
 part of my post I identify what' getting returned in the GET Call.  Thanks